# How to get all members of all groups from Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to retrieve a list of all members of all groups from the Active directory following the below format

```
Group  | Member
----------------
group1 | member1
group1 | member2
group1 | member3
group2 | member1
group2 | member4
...
```

Actually I have a PowerShell script using Quest cmdlts that retrieve the group members but the performance is very bad (up to 30hours to finish the extraction) so I am trying to retrieve members of primary groups only for the moment.
I tried with the `DSGET` command but it doesn't show the group name or ID, only a list of members

```
dsquery group -limit 0 | dsget group -members
```

I also tried with the command `CSVDE` but without success
If possible, I would like a solution that doesn't use Quest cmdlts nor AD cmdlets (Get-ADGroupMember ...)

**EDIT:**
The actal Quest cmdlts script, I have no Powershell knowledge so I can't really explain how it works...

```
$csv = get-content "C:\group_names.txt" 
$result = $csv | foreach-object {  $group=$_  get-qadgroupmember "$_"
-PageSize 500 -sizelimit 0 -indirect | 
select-object sAMAccountName,@{n="GroupName";e={$group}}  }  $result | 
export-csv C:\group_members.csv -Delimiter "|" -notypeinformation
```

Comment: What does your powershell script that uses quest cmdlet look like? Mabe we could optimize it. Do you only need direct members or indirect (through nested groups) too? Otherwise, you could use adsi. Search for "powershell get members adsi" or something.

Comment: @FrodeF. I added the actual script to the question, I prefer to get direct members and then find another solution to retrieve the childs (probably through SQL) because it takes a very long time to retrieve the child members as well

Comment: "I would like a solution that doesn't use Quest cmdlts nor AD cmdlets"  Why?  You'd have to write it like the old VBScript queries that do direct LDAP queries.  That's completely gross and bug prone and probably performs worse as well.

Comment: @BaconBits that is why I added "if possible", the reason is that I don't have privileges to Import Active Directory module neither to query Quest, also I suspect Quest server to be poorly managed and Quest cmdlts to run incredibly slow

Comment: The quest cmdlets can talk directly to a DC using LDAP. I think it's possible to use it against some type of Quest server (like you may be doing), but that's not how 99% of the modules user use it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to optimize your script using Quest cmdlets. You say that you would like to only have direct members, but still your script uses the `-Indirect` switch which like you said, makes it go terrably slow. Try this:

```
Get-Content "C:\group_names.txt" |
Foreach-Object {
    $group = $_
    Get-QADGroupMember "$_" -PageSize 500 -SizeLimit 0 |
    Select-Object sAMAccountName,@{n="GroupName";e={$group}}, type
} | Export-CSV C:\group_members.csv -Delimiter "|" -NoTypeInformation
```

You would have to create your own logic, sql script etc. to link groups together so you could find indirect members. You could do this in PowerShell too by using a function and recursion, I just didn't have time to write some at this moment. I added `type` to your output, so you could easily see which member is a nested group.